# TCL: How to dump multiple unique listbox selection in a file

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

In a `ListBox`, I want to check the names of the items selected by the user. `ListBox` does allow multiple selections. I tried writing a code for tracking the cursor selection, but I have the following problems.

1. Only the last item is printed in a file, and
2. Each new selection does print the previous selection when querying the `puts` statement.

Here is my code

```
        package require Tk
        proc selectionMade {w} {
        ##     --- loop through each selected element
                 foreach index [$w curselection] {
                       #  puts "Index --> $index"
                                 set filename selected_list.list
                                 set fileId [open $filename "w"]
                                 puts "[$w get $index]"
                                 puts $fileId "[$w get $index]"
                                 close $fileId
                                     }
                                     }

          catch {console show}
          listbox .lb -selectmode multiple
          bind .lb <<ListboxSelect>> {selectionMade %W}

          pack .lb -fill both
          set filename fsp.txt
          set fp [open $filename "r"]
          set stuff [read $fp]
          foreach item $stuff {
          .lb insert end $item
        }

 close $fp
```

Assume that my input file `fsp.txt` has the following items:

- America
- Britain
- New Zealand
- Australia
- India
- ...

Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you open the file with the "w" permission, which causes any previous contents to be overwritten.

There are a couple of solutions. First, you could open with "a" (append) mode. Or, you can open it before the loop and write to it within the loop, or you could build up a string in the loop and then write it once when the loop is finished.

For example:

```
proc selectionMade {w} {
    set filename selected_list.list
    set fileId [open $filename "w"]

    foreach index [$w curselection] {
        puts $fileId "[$w get $index]\n"
    }

    close $fileId
}
```